# Flutter plugin not installed but they are

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I have used all the answers I have found.

- installed plugins
- restarted Android Studio
- uninstalled / reinstalled Android Studio
- restarted computer
- reinstalled SDK manager
- updated Java

Flutter Doctor thinks that plugins are not installed but they are. Here is what it says:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.12.13+hotfix.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.914],
    locale en-US)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 25.0.2)

X Flutter requires Android SDK 28 and the Android BuildTools 28.0.3
      To update using sdkmanager, run:
        "C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager"
        "platforms;android-28" "build-tools;28.0.3"
      or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.

X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit
      https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web

[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)

[√] VS Code, 32-bit edition (version 1.41.1)

[√] Connected device (2 available)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check if you have added these variables to environment variables: name `ANDROID_HOME` value should be your android sdk path `C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk` and `JAVA_HOME`:  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161`

Comment: You can find all the required things in Flutter getting started doc

Comment: This should be in your `ANDROID_HOME`: `C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`. Please read here: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows if not work after those steps, let me know.

Comment: added ANDROID_HOME and my JAVA_HOME is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92  Getting the same error

Comment: @user:8822128 would you have any input to this question?

Comment: @MorganHayes Did you solve this issue? Did you installed Android studio on custom path?

Comment: I never did get it working, moved on without it.  Thanks